# How to run asp.net core api and unit test in the same solution

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a project solution where I have my ASP.NET Core Web Api and Unit test project.

I'm confused how to run integration testing for my web api having those projects in the same solution. I tried selecting multiple startup projects in the settings but what it does is run the api project and console app then closes again.

Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing